# shell scripts variable passed to awk and double quotes needed to preserve

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have some logs called ts.log that look like

```
[957670][DEBUG:2016-11-30 16:49:17,968:com.ibatis.common.logging.log4j.Log4jImpl.debug(Log4jImpl.java:26)]{pstm-9805256} Parameters: []
[957670][DEBUG:2016-11-30 16:49:17,968:com.ibatis.common.logging.log4j.Log4jImpl.debug(Log4jImpl.java:26)]{pstm-9805256} Types: []
[957670][DEBUG:2016-11-30 16:50:17,969:com.ibatis.common.logging.log4j.Log4jImpl.debug(Log4jImpl.java:26)]{rset-9805257} ResultSet
[957670][DEBUG:2016-11-30 16:51:17,969:com.ibatis.common.logging.log4j.Log4jImpl.debug(Log4jImpl.java:26)]{rset-9805257} Header: [LAST_INSERT_ID()]
[957670][DEBUG:2016-11-30 16:52:17,969:com.ibatis.common.logging.log4j.Log4jImpl.debug(Log4jImpl.java:26)]{rset-9805257} Result: [731747]
[065417][DEBUG:2016-11-30 16:53:17,986:sdk.protocol.process.InitProcessor.process(InitProcessor.java:61)]query String=requestid=10547
```

I have a script in which there's sth like

```
#!/bin/bash
begin=$1
cat ts.log | awk -F '[ ,]' '{if($2 ~/^[0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]&& $2>="16:50:17"){print $0}}'
```

instead of inputting the time like 16:50:17 I want to just pass $1 of shell to  awk so that all I need to do is ./script time:hh:mm:ss The script will look like

```
#!/bin/bash
begin=$1
cat ts.log | awk -v var=$begin -F '[ ,]' '{if($2 ~/^[0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]&& $2>="var"){print $0}}'
```

But the double quotes need to be there OR it won't work.
I tried 2>"\""var"\""
but it doesn't work.
so is there a way to keep the double quotes there?
preferred result ./script 
then extract the log from the time specified as $1.

Comment: What are all those `\1` and `\2` doing? Note you can omit `{print $0}` and directly say `awk -F '[ ,]' -v var="16:50:17" '$2>var' file` to print records whose 2nd field is bigger than the given in `var`.

Comment: Also the variable name need not be preceded by `$`

Comment: @EdMorton the double quotes are used for comparing the date, without which it won't work.  so if I manually insert the time like cat ts.log | awk -v var=$begin -F '[ ,]' '{if($2 ~/^[0-2][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]&& $2>="16:50:17"){print $0}}' , it will extract the logs from 16:50:17, but without the double quotes, it prints the whole log. So my question is if there's a way to keep the double quotes there while I can pass the variable $1 of shell to awk.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] to get a good answer. If you post the expected output given that input and clarify your requirements (including answers to specific questions like: why are you comparing $2 to a regexp that always matches your input? what does a timestamp before noon look like? what should the output be if the log file wraps to the next day? should you check the shell script "begin" input is valid?) then I expect someone can help you figure out the right approach. See [ask] if you're unsure of what's required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's many ways to do what you want.

**Option 1: Using double quotes enclosing awk program**

```
#!/bin/bash
begin=$1
awk -F '[ ,]'  "\$2 ~ /^..:..:../ && \$2 >= \"${begin}\" "  ts.log
```

- Inside double quotes strings, bash does variable substitution. So `$begin` or `${begin}` will be replaced with the shell variable value (whatever sent by the user)
- Undesired effect: awk special variables starting with `$` must be escaped with `'\'` or bash will try to replace them before execute awk.
- To get a double quote char (`"`) in bash double quote strings, it has to be escaped with `'\'`, so in bash `" \"16:50\" "` will be replaced with `"16:50"`. (This won't work with single quote strings, that don't have expansion of variables nor escaped chars at all in bash).
- To see what variable substitutions are made when bash executes the script, you can execute it with debug option (it's very enlightening):

  ```
  $ bash -x yourscript.sh 16:50
  ```

**Option 2: Using awk variables**

```
#!/bin/bash
begin=$1
awk -F '[ ,]' -v begin=$begin '$2 ~ /^..:..:../ && $2 >= begin'  ts.log
```

- Here an awk variable `begin` is created with option `-v varname=value`.
- Awk variables can be used in any place of awk program as any other awk variable (don't need double quotes nor `$`).

There are other options, but I think you can work with these two.

In both options I've changed a bit your script:

- It doesn't need `cat` to send data to `awk`, because `awk` can execute your program in one or more data files sent as parameters after your program.
- Your awk program doesn't need include `print` at all (as @fedorqui said), because a basic awk program is composed by pairs of `pattern {code}`, where pattern is the same as you used in the `if` sentence, and the default code is `{print $0}`.
- I've also changed the time pattern, primarly to clarify the script, but in a log file there's almost no chance that exists some 8 char length string that has 2 colons inside (regexp: `.` repaces any char)

Comment: This works ! thanks a lot for the explanation! This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Downvoted because Option 1 is complicated and fragile with zero benefits over other approaches and so should never be used, and Option 2 unnecessarily tests $2 and will fail in the comparison when different timestamps appear in the input file and will produce syntax errors or security problems given different script parameters.

Comment: @EdMorton, it's your opinion, and a fragile one (that's mine).

Comment: Yes it is my opinion but I've had over a quarter century of awk programming experience, and an additional 10 or so with shell, to inform that opinion so YMMV in dismissing it. Good luck anyway though.

Comment: @WPomier Sure, but I'm new to Stackoverflow. I don't know how I can do this. There doesn't seem to be an accept button anywhere on the page.

Comment: @RandixLaiRandy, [See this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235)

Comment: @EdMorton, Well, I have 27y in ksh + awk (since AT&T Unix SysV SVR4), but I'm only a month answering in SO. So, I think you're the experienced one :-)

Comment: Then I can understand you not knowing to encourage posters to follow the instruction at [ask] that make this site usable by people searching for answers to similar questions as it's intended, but you REALLY should know better than to leave shell variables unquoted for no reason and to enclose scripts in double quotes, etc.